# Driving Ignition Coil with Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, automotive, coil

I am trying to design a circuit to drive an ignition coil in an automotive application using a microcontroller. The microcontroller operates on a 5VDC input and puts out a 3.3V and 4mA digital signal from its pins. Attached is a picture of the circuit I have so far.

There are a few issues I know I need to resolve:

1. I don’t know what model of MOSFET to use here. I’m having trouble using the digikey search and filter functions to figure out what I need. I am pretty certain I need an n channel enhancement mode MOSFET, though.
2. I don’t know if I need to add another MOSFET before the one I already have in the circuit to drive it. Since I’m only working with 4mA and I need to drive upwards of 10A to the coil, I feel like I may need another MOSFET in between to step up the power to drive the main power MOSFET.
3. I don’t know if I need additional protections added into my circuit. I’ve been reading about flywheel or flyback diodes, adding a resistor and capacitor in parallel with the coil, and zener diodes. These are beyond what I know about electronics.

If you notice anything else wrong with my circuit please let me know. I don’t usually work with these kind of components; I’m used to just wiring everything up to the car battery.

Thanks,
Zack[image: circuit draft]

Edit: updated schematic 1:
[image]

Edit 2: Is an IGBT what I need maybe? [This](https:///https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/mx3tybso42/FAIRS45563-1.pdf?t.download=true&u=5oefqw) looks like it could do what I want? Having trouble understanding if it meets the specs I need, though. I've never read anything about IGBTs until today.

Comment: I think you should consider using a MOSFET gate driver IC for this circuit to go between your micro and the big MOSFET driving the ignition coil. For power switching applications like this it's important to ensure fast turn-on and turn-off times - which is something you don't really want to bother with trying to achieve with extra discrete components when you could just drop in a single IC.

Comment: It might also benefit you to investigate using a 'snubber' circuit across the MOSFET instead of just the single flyback diode.

Comment: I think it would be better if you connect drain of first mosfet to the gate of second mosfet in your updated schematic.

Comment: Okay, I have narrowed my choices for Ignition Specific IGBTs to these, but having trouble figuring out which meet my specs. Going to continue researching. Any input it appreciated. Also exploring the possibility of a gate driver IC and MOSFET combo like @brhans suggested.

Comment: @knight If I were to do that, would I then need a p channel mosfet for the first one?

Comment: @Zsn0w n channel would be fine

Answer (score 2):

With an ignition coil you need to let it flyback to 300-400V otherwise you won’t get much of a spark. As the OP has found, there are specific devices that are designed to allow this.

The other consideration is current limiting. With an ignition coil you apply current, then hold it until you want to fire - you turn the igbt off. Older ignition coils used with points are designed to not saturate whereas modern coils will and require the current to be limited.

There’s plenty of information and examples on the megasquirt site. You might want to consider a coil driver module that are common spare parts for cars or maybe a ignition module that incorporates the required circuitry and just needs a 5V signal to trigger. I’ve used Toyota Corolla coil on plug units that have this feature.

Comment: https://www.mouser.com/c/semiconductors/power-management-ics/motor-motion-ignition-controllers-drivers/?m=onsemi&product=Electronic%20Ignition%20Drivers&instock=y&normallystocked=y I'm thinking these are what I need to give me the flyback you're talking about? Having trouble understanding what exactly the voltage clamping they talk about is. Is that just the flyback limiting? Continuing to research all of these to try to decide which one of these to go with/if they'll accomplish what I need. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Actualy, you dont need flyback circuit. Some coils work on DC (battery source) some is CDI and others.. Most importan point which is best for your works ! Use an 12V coil (with trigger, this got 3 pin) and do what you want(can use an optocoupler for isolation+ gate driver). Don't forget about joule calculation, more ignitition power isn't perfect solution, can splash everywhere ! Spark plug distance limited your energy level, you can't apply more than required. (Test : Connect more than one coil to the coil and make sure one spark plug fires at a time.)

Comment: Why one spark plug can fire ?  Common AC/DC source waste alot enegy, If you have too much spark plug energy, you may not have enough energy for the next times(missfire).

Answer (score 1):

1. You need a beefy power MOSFET such as the IRF3205. But you need a gate-source
   voltage of higher than 3.3V to fully turn ON the power MOSFET. Check the
   datasheet for more details.
2. Yes, add a bjt or mosfet and connect collector/drain to gate of power mosfet.
3. Again, you need a power semiconductor component, a diode, between Supply and
   Drain. Anode of diode to drain and cathode to supply voltage.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I’ll attach an updated schematic, let me know if that’s what you mean and if I have the diodes correct if you can. Just need to find a mosfet to use for the first part now. Think based on what I drew up it needs to be able to handle 10 V at .5 A to be safe. Maybe I should use bigger resistors on the divider going into the first MOSFET to the amperage down more? Voltage needs to be about 8 from the data sheet of the IRF3205 I think? Thanks again.

Comment: I am thinking maybe 500 and 1000 ohms for the resistors in the voltage divider because that gives me between 7.7 and 9.7 volts in the normal car battery voltage range of 12-14.5 and limits the amps to under 30 milliamps.

Comment: Cascading two MOSFETS like that means you need to add the Vgs values together, so your micro has no hope of turning them both fully on with a 3.3V output. You'd be far better using a Darlington NPN.

Comment: It can't just use the ~8 Volts I have coming in off of the 12-14V battery to turn the second MOSFET on? Why does it add  the Vgs together? I had looked at BJTs but I was afraid they might not be fast enough, since I couldn't find any listed switching times in the datasheets for them like I could in MOSFET sheets and they are supposed to be slower.

Comment: The source of the first connects to the gate of the second, so the Vgs of the first adds to the Vgs of the second. Though it's largely academic as you won't even be able to turn the IRF3205 on enough with just 3.3V

Comment: I must be completely misunderstanding something about how MOSFETs operate then... If the Vgs of the first one is 3.3V coming in the gate and that turns it on all the way, wouldn't the 8V then be passed through the drain and source and go into the gate of the second MOSFET, turning it on all the way? Or you're saying somehow the Vgs requirement of the second one raises from 8 to 11.3 when you have another MOSFET driving it?

Comment: What matters is the voltage between gate and source (Vgs). As the first MOSFET turns on, current will start to flow through the 10k resistor, raising the voltage at the source and therefore reducing Vgs. The voltage at the source can never be more than the gate voltage less the Vgs threshold voltage.

Comment: So... MOSFETs switch higher CURRENTS, while a BJT would allow me to switch higher VOLTAGES? Maybe my best option is one BJT and one MOSFET so that I could step up both of them? My concern is just with delay in the switching. Do you know of any resources on switching times of BJTs? I have tried to search for it, but haven't found anything useful. I am working within the span of milliseconds that I need to leave the coil powered on, so I need switching in microseconds.

Comment: BJT switching speed is the least of your worries, You need to learn a lot more about how these components work and how to use them before designing a circuit like this.

Comment: I went to school for computer science, so the microcontroller programming is more my speed, not the circuit design. Really if I could just find the right driver for the coil then I shouldn't need to do much else in the way of the wiring. It's just driving one coil. I think this may do what I need: https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/onsemi-Fairchild/ISL9V3040S3ST?qs=taDQNAOcNDEC%2FG%252BX7GV%252BKg%3D%3D

Comment: You said you need to handle 10V at 0.5A, so you are good with IRFZ44N. No need for the 3205. @Zsn0w

Comment: Well the 10V 0.5A was to saturate the 3205 if I was doing two MOSFETs in a row, but Finbarr said that won't work because the Vgs stacks.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this done with an NPN bipolar transistor for the positive drive of the coil waveform and an PNP for the negative. You have to look at the coil pack to see whether it uses a positive or negative waveform to trigger.  Note the coil received 12v on a separate input - the trigger signal is fine at 5V - for a 4 wire coil pack, which seem very popular.

[image]

Comment: I get the impression from the OP's question that it's an old fashioned "raw" ignition coil - basically just a very high-turns-ratio autotransformer - and if that's the case it needs to driven pretty hard by an open-collector or open-drain, and little 2N2222/3906 BJTs + 10R series resistor won't even begin to do the job. But that impression of mine could easily just be my own preconceptions kicking in because it's what I did 15-ish years ago :P. @Zsn0w can you clarify for us what kind of ignition coil you're using?

Comment: @brhans that is correct, I am working with an old school cylinder ignition coil. Specifically, I am thinking about using this Pertronix model https://pertronixbrands.com/products/pertronix-40011-flame-thrower-coil-40-000-volt-1-5-ohm-black?variant=31797269037092. I have also been looking at the e-core style coils, but it is hard to find information on the factory coils re: what circuitry they do/do not already have inside them and what their specs are.